# SSL, CSR: should I include -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----?

Tags: ssl, csr

I need to submit my CSR certificate (generated with openSSL) to my ssl provider.

I need to copy paste it in a text area. I was wondering if I should copy paste also the beginning and the end:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

and

-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

or not...
thanks!

**Update**

```
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: www.mydomain.com
Email Address []: ---@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Cert Authorities expect that to be included

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: I've submitted the certificated and now I need to verify the domain ownership. 1. How long does it take to get the email from the ssl provider (godaddy) 2. This is my configuration (see question)

Comment: My email address is just gmail and not the same domain.. I've just realized now this can be an issue.. is it ?

Comment: Apparently the email has been sent to my provider. I guess I have to change the WHOIS settings. But I cannot do it from my VPS control panel. How can I change the confirmation email for the SSL certificate ?

Comment: @Patrick you'll need to contact your domain's registrar (or use their website) to change the WHOIS settings.  If your VPS provider registered the domain for you, you'll need to have them change the information if they don't provide a method in the control panel.